# Where there is a NaN in a Pandas Column I want to replace with a 1 except for the Totals which need to sum the 1's

Tags: python, pandas

In the Month Return Column I need to replace NaN with a 1 except for the ros in the Category Column with the "TOTAL". I need those to sum the 1's up just after the previous "TOTAL" row. Lengths of Grouped rows (by date and Account) can vary by length.

```
Return Date    Account      Category    Month Return
 7/31/2003      abcdef       BOND        NaN
 7/31/2003      abcdef       CASH        NaN
 7/31/2003      abcdef       EQUITY      NaN
 7/31/2003      abcdef       TOTAL       Nan
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       BOND        0.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       CASH        0.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       EQUITY      1.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       TOTAL       1.75
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       BOND        NaN
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       CASH        NaN
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       EQUITY      NaN
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       REAL        NaN
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       TOTAL       Nan
```

Want it to look something like this:

```
Return Date    Account      Category    Month Return
 7/31/2003      abcdef       BOND        1
 7/31/2003      abcdef       CASH        1
 7/31/2003      abcdef       EQUITY      1
 7/31/2003      abcdef       TOTAL       3
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       BOND        0.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       CASH        0.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       EQUITY      1.25
 7/31/2003      ghijkl       TOTAL       1.75
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       BOND        1
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       CASH        1
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       EQUITY      1
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       REAL        1
 7/31/2003      mnopqr       TOTAL       4
```

Comment: is the pair `Return Date, Account` unique?

Comment: Yes it would be unique. Only one account can be associated with one return date. But they can repeat with the category since an account can be broken up into several asset classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
c=df['Category'].ne('TOTAL')
df.loc[c,'Month_Return']=df.loc[c,'Month_Return'].fillna(1)
fill=df.groupby('Account')['Month_Return'].apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).cumsum())
df['Month_Return'].fillna(fill,inplace=True)
print(df)

   Return_Date Account Category Month_Return
0    7/31/2003  abcdef     BOND            1
1    7/31/2003  abcdef     CASH            1
2    7/31/2003  abcdef   EQUITY            1
3    7/31/2003  abcdef    TOTAL            3
4    7/31/2003  ghijkl     BOND         0.25
5    7/31/2003  ghijkl     CASH         0.25
6    7/31/2003  ghijkl   EQUITY         1.25
7    7/31/2003  ghijkl    TOTAL         1.75
8    7/31/2003  mnopqr     BOND            1
9    7/31/2003  mnopqr     CASH            1
10   7/31/2003  mnopqr   EQUITY            1
11   7/31/2003  mnopqr     REAL            1
12   7/31/2003  mnopqr    TOTAL            4
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: There is a problem unforunatley. This works perfectly for example problem I gave but the reality that it is much much longer. 45, 000 rows actually.

When I run this it seems to work but I'm realizing that every subsequent Total sums all the 1's that come before. So the first total will be 5 which will be right and the second total would be 10 and the next 15.

It should only sum to values after the previous total. So the totals would be something like 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 6 and so on

Comment: Thanks for explaining the mistake. I have updated the code and it seems that there are no errors!

Answer (score 1):

#### `transform` mixed in there somewhere

```
mask = df['Category'].eq('TOTAL')
ones = df['Month Return'].fillna(1).mask(mask)
tots = ones.groupby(df['Account']).transform('sum')
df['Month Return'] = ones.fillna(tots)

df

   Return Date Account Category  Month Return
0    7/31/2003  abcdef     BOND          1.00
1    7/31/2003  abcdef     CASH          1.00
2    7/31/2003  abcdef   EQUITY          1.00
3    7/31/2003  abcdef    TOTAL          3.00
4    7/31/2003  ghijkl     BOND          0.25
5    7/31/2003  ghijkl     CASH          0.25
6    7/31/2003  ghijkl   EQUITY          1.25
7    7/31/2003  ghijkl    TOTAL          1.75
8    7/31/2003  mnopqr     BOND          1.00
9    7/31/2003  mnopqr     CASH          1.00
10   7/31/2003  mnopqr   EQUITY          1.00
11   7/31/2003  mnopqr     REAL          1.00
12   7/31/2003  mnopqr    TOTAL          4.00
```

---

#### Details

```
mask = df['Category'].eq('TOTAL')
```

I'm going to use this to blot out values where `mask` is `True` but I wanted my code to be prettier.

```
ones = df['Month Return'].fillna(1) ...
```

This is where I fill in missing bits with `1`

```
ones = df['Month Return'].fillna(1).mask(mask)
```

And subsequently blot out the rows where `mask` is `True` or `Category` is `TOTAL`.  Keep in mind that this removes the values where we already had a `'Month Return'` in a `'TOTAL'` row.  But that's ok, I'll recalculate in a bit.

```
tots = ones.groupby(df['Account']).transform('sum')
```

This gets me a series whose index matches my dataframe and makes it easier to `fillna` because Pandas will know which rows to fill.

```
df['Month Return'] = ones.fillna(tots)
```

At this point, the only rows in `ones` that have `NaN` values are the ones with `'TOTAL'` in the `'Category'` column.  And those are exactly the ones, I'm going to fill with the sum for each `'Account'`.

Comment: Should be accepted answer, since only vectorized solutions are used +  detailed explanation.